# Query to combine two tables group by month

Tags: mysql, join

I have tried to connect two tables by join and group them to get the count. But unfortunately, these two tables don't have any common value to join (Or I have misunderstood the solutions).

```
select date_format(check_in.date,'%M') as Month, count(check_in.Id) as checkInCount 
from check_in 
group by month(check_in.date);
```

| Month | checkInCount |
| --- | --- |
| July | 1 |
| October | 2 |

This is the first table.

```
select date_format(reservation.date,'%M') as Month, count(reservation.id) as reserveCount 
from reservation
group by month(reservation.date);
```

| Month | reserveCount |
| --- | --- |
| July | 3 |
| October | 5 |

This is the second table.
I want to show these two tables in one table.

| Month | checkInCount | reserveCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| July | 1 | 3 |
| October | 2 | 5 |

Thank you for trying this and sorry if this is too easy.

Comment: Use these queries as subqueries in FROM, join them by month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to join the result by `month` from your two subqueries.
This query assume all the `month` (July, August, September...) present in your subqueries `monthCheckInStat`, `monthCheckOutStat`, even if the count is 0

```
SELECT monthCheckInStat.Month, monthCheckInStat.checkInCount, monthCheckOutStat.reserveCount
FROM
(
    select date_format(check_in.date,'%M') as Month, count(check_in.Id) as checkInCount 
    from check_in 
    group by month(check_in.date)
) monthCheckInStat
INNER JOIN
(
    select date_format(reservation.date,'%M') as Month, count(reservation.id) as reserveCount 
    from reservation
    group by month(reservation.date)
) monthCheckOutStat
ON monthCheckInStat.Month = monthCheckOutStat.Month;
```

Comment: It worked 90% sir. But the thing is it outcome only the months that both tables commonly have. But I want all the months. If one table doesn't have any value to that month, then it must come "0". Is it possible sir?